# Why is my ScrollView ContentOffset changing to random 83 when device rotation happens?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2

I am having this strange problem, where a totally in autolayout created scrollview is settings its contentoffset to a random value of 83, if I switch from landscape to portrait on page 2/2.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set contentOffset when device rotation happens

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    }];
}
```